# (SOLVED) - Error: "The device does not have the necessary services" when using bluetooth to browse files on Galaxy S7 Edge

Tags: macos, bluetooth, file-transfer, android

How do I get the "necessary services" on my Galaxy S7 Edge phone using Android Marshmallow so I can use bluetooth to browse and transfer files between my Macbook Pro and my phone?

The error message "The device does not have the necessary services" shows up after I click the "Browse" button on the "Browse Device" window after selecting my phone as the Bluetooth device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software.

Comment: I disagree. Using android with a MacBook is totally on topic. Now, it might be better on the android site - but it's on topic here.

Comment: I just had the same problem when I was trying to pair my S7 to my Macbook Air. It is a very valid Apple hardware related problem. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: yeah nothing needs to be done in windows, this is an osx problem

Comment: I'm agree, I use el capitan, and is a mac problem, any solution ?, please stop vote against , have you a lot of free time to block question you don't like?

Comment: actually it's NOT a problem of Apple hardware

Answer (score 1):

Even if it should be part of the Android OS, looks like the OBEX FTP service is not included.
I searched the Play Store and there is at least one program that allows for browsing from a paired device (in this case my Mac) and it's: [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) (that also works as a client).
Remember to go into the app settings to select which folder will be used as a root for the server, otherwise it's set to /store/emulated/0

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this on rawinfopages.com.
Thank you guys!

1. System Preferences > Sharing
2. Select Bluetooth Sharing to see the settings
3. You can do what you want here. I changed to "Ask What to Do" for both when receiving items and when other devices browse
4. Tick Bluetooth Sharing to turn the service on
5. Then you're set to share from your phone over bluetooth to your Mac, following instructions on screen

Worked for me 2020 March 7 (Happy Women's Day :) transferring from a Galaxy S6 to macOS Catalina .

I was also getting the same error message "The device does not have the necessary services" before doing the above and sucessfully transferring a photo :)

all the best
Dave

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I can now transfer files between my Samsung S9 Android phone and MacBook.